# Create a new column from a pandas DataFrame based on a numeric column and indices in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains a numeric column and a list that contains strings as elements. I want to create a new column in that data frame where each number in the numeric column corresponds to the index of the list.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

bar = ['cat','dog','chicken']
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[0,0,1,1,2,2]})
```

Expected output:

```
   foo      bar
0    0      cat
1    0      cat
2    1      dog
3    1      dog
4    2  chicken
5    2  chicken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast and quick alternative is to create an array with list comprehension:

```
df['bar'] = [bar[x] for x in df['foo']]
```

Another option using `apply`:

```
df['bar'] = df['foo'].apply(lambda x: bar[x])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   foo      bar
0    0      cat
1    0      cat
2    1      dog
3    1      dog
4    2  chicken
5    2  chicken
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use numpy

```
import numpy as np
df['bar'] = np.array(bar)[df['foo'].values]
```

It scales better for bigger datasets like the following:

```
bar = ['cat','dog','chicken']
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':np.random.choice(np.arange(3), 10000000)})
```